# Highslide In Page Z-Index

Tags: css, highslide

I have a problem with the z index Position of an inPage galery on my page.

I have tried the hs.zIndexCounter attribut, that do not work out. My navi has z-index 10000.

Here my live example:
[Live Example](http://www.angel-holidays.com/Deutsch/Ferienvilla-Mallorca/Porto_Petro/01974.html)

Thank you for your help,

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`hs.zIndexCounter` isn’t overrideable inline, which mean you can’t put it in the `var`. (See “Details” in the reference page: http://highslide.com/ref/hs.zIndexCounter)
You need to set it as a global variable like this (outside the `var`):

```
hs.zIndexCounter = 1;
```